# What is the intuition behind signed measures?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have a rather basic question, and I cannot really find an answer around.

> What is the intuition behind the introduction of ***signed*** measures?

I am not referring to the mathematical properties of these objects. Rather, the problem is to get what we capture with them (concrete examples, etc).

Any feedback is most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

One example comes from physics: distance vs. displacement.

Distilling this to a signed measure would be like standing in front of an building layout poster with a "You Are Here" marker.  If you go right in the hallway, that's a positive displacement; if you go left, that's a negative displacement.

But taking the *distance* from the marker is positive, regardless of whether you go left or right.

If you were to take an expected value of the displacement of each room in the hallway from the point, it would be close to zero if you were near the center.  But the (unsigned) distance would be about $1/4$ of the length of the hallway.

Does this help a bit?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually it does, even if I am not sure about the part in between *"If you were to take... length of the hallway."*

Comment: If I'm right in the middle of the hallway, and the rooms are symmetric about that point, then the expected value of the displacement from that point to the rooms would be zero (all of the positives would cancel the negatives).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Indeed, that was clear. The problem I had was with the other statement concerning the $1/4$. Intuitively I would say that if the EV of the signed measure is in $(-\varepsilon, +\varepsilon)$, the EV of the measure should be close to the actual length of the measure, which was not mentioned. Hence, the $1/4$ looked arbitrary. But maybe I am missing something.